# Execute SQL script on multiple MDF files

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-express, sqlcmd, localdb

I would like to run an instance-ignorant `.sql` script on multiple detached `.mdf` files. What seemed most logical to me was something for `sqlcmd` akin to `attachdbfilename=`, like:

```
sqlcmd -f "database.mdf" -i "process.sql"
```

I swear I've done this since LocalDB came out, and seem to recall it was a flag not present in prior versions of `sqlcmd`. Unfortunately, it's not in the docs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

---

**Tangent**

I've had a challenge understanding the distinct operating modes, as I've been searching for tools to accomplish the above. It would help if you could confirm that I've summarized them correctly here:

I think I have 3 supported modes for how to access SQL Server 2012 databases on my development computer using SQL Server Express. I've expressed these as the identifying characteristics of their provider connection strings.

1. `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS`
2. `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf`
3. `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0`
4. `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf`

These options run on the 'backend' as:

1. A fully-functioning service-based network-stack-connectable (with limits) SQL Server
2. An application-in-process SQL Server, identified as a "SQL Server Database File" connection (it locks process-exclusive access to the `.MDF`), vs. the other modes which are identified as "SQL Server" connections.
3. An installable feature hybrid between #1 and #3. The SQL *Client* starts a locally-piped instance on-demand. Runs out-of-process but shares security context with caller.
4. Identical operation mode to #3 (although note that #1 and #2 are very different).

All three of these methods are still supported.